# Swift 3 | TableView ScrollToTop on reloadData with dynamic cell size

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, scrolltop

I have a TableView with dynamic cell size :

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 20
```

I have cells with texts inside and, of course, the text Height can change in function of its content.

Sometimes I have only one line, sometimes I have more, it means sometimes my cells does 20 height, sometimes more.

I have an issue when I try to reload my tableview datas and scroll to the top.

This is what I do :

```
myTableViewDatas = newDatas
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
tableView.reloadData()
```

It is hard to show you this case but It doesn't scroll to `Y = 0`, it scrolls to `Y = 100` or something like that. Because my cell size changes in function of the content to display.

If I remove dynamic size and do :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```

And still scroll to the top with :

```
myTableViewDatas = newDatas
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
tableView.reloadData()
```

==> This is working, I scroll to `Y = 0`

I think I tried anything :

- scrollToRow
- scrollRectToVisible
- scrollsToTop

I still have the issue.
The only way this is working is if I delay the `reloadData` :

```
myTableViewDatas = newDatas
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is working but It creates a "glitch" => It displays new datas then automatically scroll to top, this is disturbing for the user.

The other solution is to use "reloadSections" :

```
myTableViewDatas = newDatas
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none) // I have only one section
```

It works too but it is also creating a "glitch", this is like TableView is reloaded with an animation (even if I set .none) where cells displayed are reduced / enlarged in function of new datas.

I really can't find a "proper" solution to do this, does anyone as already encountered this issue ? TY

Comment: What if you change the order of the calls? You can scroll to the top and then reload the data.

Comment: @Holly Thanks for your answer, If I change the order of the call => Nothing is happening, the only way it scrolls to the top is if I set contentOffset to 0 and then reload datas.

Comment: What thread are you performing that code from?

Comment: @Holly Everything is done in the main thread, I have IBAction where user can filter the result displayed in TableView

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes you search complicated solutions and It is simple in fact.
I did : 
- reload first
- scrollToIndexPath 0 second
-> It works

```
myTableViewDatas = newDatas
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. [UITableView reloadData] doesn't work how we expected.
It doesn't layout tableView from the cleanslate.

> > Reloads everything from scratch. Redisplays visible rows. Note that this will cause any existing drop placeholder rows to be removed.

It says redisplays visible rows. So this is what I did.

```
data = nil;  // clear data.

[tableView reloadData];  // reloadd tableView so make it empty.

[tableView setNeedsLayout];  // layout tableView.
[tableView layoutIfNeeded];

data = the data;  // set the data you want to display.

[tableView reloadData];   // reload tableView
```